# How to read one >>new<< item from a firebase elegantly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase

I am outputing a result of a successful read to a page, so I've only got one attempt before the headers are set and the page shipped.

I need to read **one new value**, which is supposed to be created some time **after** a listener was initiated, in other words, I don't want to read already present data because of the aforementioned reasons.

Right now, this is what I've got:

```
let timestamp = Date.now()
fbref.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

  if (snapshot.val().createdAt > timestamp) {
    res.send('ok') // express.js
    fbref.off()
  }

});
```

The problem is that this is not an elegant solution as I need to 1) start listening, 2) filter out the values and continue listening for future items. 3) Once the first genuinely new item arrives, I unsubscribe and output the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds horrible indeed. This should accomplish the same and pull down a lot less data:

```
let timestamp = Date.now()
let newItemQuery = fbref.orderByChild('createdAt').startAt(timestamp);
newItemQuery.on('child_added', ...
```

Comment: I am using `push`, so the children are already sorted, can it be done without the `.orderByChild`? Also I am sending one initial message together with the listener, and later a bot creates a new item, so `timestamp+1` worked better for me. Thanks!